# What is wrong with this make file? (The error is: make *** No rule to make target)

Tags: makefile, fortran

I'm trying to compile and run XROTOR on my Windows 7 laptop. I have downloaded Cygwin, as well as XROTOR (http://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/xrotor/)

From the README...

```
Build Sequence
--------------
To install, first build the plot library in  ./plotlib  ...

 % cd plotlib
 % make libPlt.a

Then build the programs in  ./bin  ...

 % make xrotor
 % make jplot
```

When I go to "make libPlt.a" I get an error that says:

make: * ** No rule to make target: 'libPlt.a'. Stop.

What silly mistake am I making?

Here's the make file I believe:

```
#=======================================#
# Makefile options for Xplot11 library  #
#   Set up or select a set of compile   #
#   options for your system             # 
#=======================================#


# Set library name 
PLTLIB = libPlt_gDP.a

# Some fortrans need trailing underscores in C interface symbols (see Xwin.c)
# This should work for most of the "unix" fortran compilers
DEFINE = -DUNDERSCORE

FC = gfortran
CC  = gcc
DP = -fdefault-real-8

FFLAGS  = -O2 $(DP)
CFLAGS  = -O2 $(DEFINE)
AR = ar r
RANLIB = ranlib 
LINKLIB = -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11
```

Actually! I think this is the makefile (it's called makefile so I'm assuming as much)

```
#***********************************************************************
#    Module:  Makefile
# 
#    Copyright (C) 1996 Harold Youngren, Mark Drela 
# 
#    This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#    modify it under the terms of the GNU Library General Public
#    License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
#    version 2 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#    This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
#    Library General Public License for more details.
#
#    You should have received a copy of the GNU Library General Public
#    License along with this library; if not, write to the Free
#    Software Foundation, Inc., 675 Mass Ave, Cambridge, MA 02139, USA.
# 
#    Report problems to:    guppy@maine.com 
#                        or drela@mit.edu  
#***********************************************************************


#================================#
# Makefile for Xplot11 library   #
#  edit the config.make file to  #
#  set specific options for your #
#  system                        #
#================================#

# Point to your install directory
#INSTALLDIR = /home/codes/bin
#INSTALLDIR = /usr/local/lib
INSTALLDIR = .

# Use these to set default library name (overridden in config.make file) 
PLTLIB = libPlt.a
#PLTLIB = libPltDP.a


###========================================================
###  Basic plot library object files
OBJ     = plt_base.o plt_font.o plt_util.o plt_color.o \
          set_subs.o gw_subs.o ps_subs.o Xwin.o
OBJMISC =
OBJ3D   =
OBJOLD  =

###--------------------------------------------------------
###  Uncomment to add the old plot compatibility routines
OBJOLD  = plt_old.o

###--------------------------------------------------------
###  Uncomment to add the primitive 3D-view routines
OBJ3D  = plt_3D.o

###--------------------------------------------------------
###  Uncomment for f77 compiler w/o AND() and RSHIFT/LSHIFT functions.
###   This adds some functions to duplicate these using IAND and ISHFT
###   which often appear in these offending fortran's libraries.
###   The compilers that this has affected include:
###      HPUX f77
###      Absoft f77 on Linux
###
#OBJMISC = util-ops.o


###-------------------------------------------------------------------------
### Set compiler, compiler flags, name of output object library
include ./config.make


###-------------------------------------------------------------------------
### Basic make targets - build library, test programs

$(PLTLIB):  $(OBJ) $(OBJOLD) $(OBJ3D) $(OBJMISC)
    $(AR)     $(PLTLIB) $(OBJ) $(OBJOLD) $(OBJ3D) $(OBJMISC)
    $(RANLIB) $(PLTLIB)

test:  $(PLTLIB)
    (cd examples; make test)


###-------------------------------------------------------------------------
### Utility functions - install the library, clean the directory

install:  $(PLTLIB)
    mv $(PLTLIB) $(INSTALLDIR)
    $(RANLIB)   $(INSTALLDIR)/$(PLTLIB)

clean:
    -/bin/rm $(OBJ) $(OBJOLD) $(OBJ3D) $(OBJMISC)
    -/bin/rm $(PLTLIB)
    -/bin/rm plot*.ps
    (cd examples; make clean)


###-------------------------------------------------------------------------
### compile plot package routines

plt_base.o: plt_base.f pltlib.inc
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS)  plt_base.f

plt_color.o: plt_color.f  pltlib.inc
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS)  plt_color.f

plt_font.o: plt_font.f CHAR.INC SLAN.INC MATH.INC SYMB.INC
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS)  plt_font.f

plt_util.o: plt_util.f
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS)  plt_util.f

plt_3D.o: plt_3D.f
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS)  plt_3D.f

plt_old.o: plt_old.f pltlib.inc
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS)  plt_old.f

set_subs.o: set_subs.f  pltlib.inc
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS)  set_subs.f

gw_subs.o: gw_subs.f  pltlib.inc
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS)  gw_subs.f

ps_subs.o: ps_subs.f  pltlib.inc
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS)  ps_subs.f

util-ops.o: util-ops.f 
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS)  util-ops.f

Xwin.o: Xwin.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) Xwin.c


### May need to specify these on a brain-dead make system
#.f.o:  $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) $<
#.c.o:  $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<
```

If you need any more information, just ask!

UPDATE: I typed in "make libPLT_gDP.a"

[image]

Comment: Are you missing X11 and its libraries and headers?

Comment: Thank you for responding!
I am reinstalling Cygwin with the X11 folder all checked this time!

Comment: So it's really a discrepancy between the actual target name and the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I didn't install the X11 things when I was installing Cygwin. Moral of the story, make sure to check "make" as well as all the X11 things when installing Cygwin (might as well check all the fortran things too (use search)). Anyways, don't worry about XRotor, download CRotor instead. Look at it's documentation and you should be able to figure out how to make. Actually, here's a section of the README that you might find useful:

```
 % cd plotlib
 % make libPlt.a

Then build the programs in  ./bin  ...

 % make xrotor
 % make jplot


Documentation
-------------
User Guide is in the  xrotor.doc  file.  If impatient, you can just
run XROTOR:

 % xrotor
```